# Excel VBA: Making a list of all files in a folder, including hyperlinks and copy data from each Excel file it finds

Tags: vba, excel, copy

My first post here, so be gentle :)

Here is the situation. I'm working on a big softwareproject as a softwaretester. At the moment we are starting with an enormous overhaul of the application wich results in a lot of Excel files with testcases and status reports (over 200 files in the coming months). To follow progress of everything we need an Excelsheet wich can make a list of all the files including hyperlinks and read the status information from each file when it exists.

I've found loads of tutorials on making a list of all the files in a folder and giving them hyperlinks. Currently i'm using the code from this website: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=232

So now i can make a list of all the files in the folder i can select from a pop-up screen.

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Function Excludes(Ext As String) As Boolean
     'Function purpose:  To exclude listed file extensions from hyperlink listing

    Dim X, NumPos As Long

     'Enter/adjust file extensions to EXCLUDE from listing here:
    X = Array("exe", "bat", "dll", "zip", "txt", "xlsm", "html", "htm", "xml")

    On Error Resume Next
    NumPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Ext, X, 0)
    If NumPos > 0 Then Excludes = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function


Sub HyperlinkFileList()
     'Macro purpose:  To create a hyperlinked list of all files in a user
     'specified directory, including file size and date last modified
     'NOTE:  The 'TextToDisplay' property (of the Hyperlink object) was added
     'in Excel 2000.  This code tests the Excel version and does not use the
     'Texttodisplay property if using XL 97.

    Dim fso As Object, _
    ShellApp As Object, _
    File As Object, _
    SubFolder As Object, _
    Directory As String, _
    Problem As Boolean, _
    ExcelVer As Integer

     'Turn off screen flashing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     ' Clear sheet
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select

     'Create objects to get a listing of all files in the directory
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

     'Prompt user to select a directory
    Do
        Problem = False
        Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
        Browseforfolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, "D:")
        'Browseforfolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, "D:\JBOSS\Testdossier")

        On Error Resume Next
         'Evaluate if directory is valid
        Directory = ShellApp.self.Path
        Set SubFolder = fso.GetFolder(Directory).Files
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            If MsgBox("You did not choose a valid directory!" & vbCrLf & _
            "Would you like to try again?", vbYesNoCancel, _
            "Directory Required") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
            Problem = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop Until Problem = False

     'Set up the headers on the worksheet
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("A1")
            .Value = "Listing of all files in:"
            .ColumnWidth = 40
             'If Excel 2000 or greater, add hyperlink with file name
             'displayed.  If earlier, add hyperlink with full path displayed
            If Val(Application.Version) > 8 Then 'Using XL2000+
                .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=.Offset(0, 1), _
                Address:=Directory, _
                TextToDisplay:=Directory
            Else 'Using XL97
                .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=.Offset(0, 1), _
                Address:=Directory
            End If
        End With
        With .Range("A2")
            .Value = "File Name"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            .ColumnWidth = 50
            With .Offset(0, 1)
                .ColumnWidth = 15
                .Value = "Date Modified"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 2)
                .ColumnWidth = 12
                .Value = "File Size (Kb)"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 3)
                .ColumnWidth = 18
                .Value = "Status testdossier"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 4)
                .ColumnWidth = 22
                .Value = "Totaal aantal testgevallen"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 5)
                .ColumnWidth = 15
                .Value = "Uitgevoerd"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 6)
                .ColumnWidth = 15
                .Value = "Akkoord"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 7)
                .ColumnWidth = 6
                .Value = "OK"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 8)
                .ColumnWidth = 6
                .Value = "NOK"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        End With
    End With

     'Adds each file, details and hyperlinks to the list
    For Each File In SubFolder
            If Not Excludes(Right(File.Path, 3)) = True Then
                With ActiveSheet
                     'If Excel 2000 or greater, add hyperlink with file name
                     'displayed.  If earlier, add hyperlink with full path displayed
                    If Val(Application.Version) > 8 Then 'Using XL2000+
                        .Hyperlinks.Add _
                        Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
                        Address:=File.Path, _
                        TextToDisplay:=File.Name
                    Else 'Using XL97
                        .Hyperlinks.Add _
                        Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
                        Address:=File.Path
                    End If
                    'Add date last modified, and size in KB
                    With .Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
                        .Offset(0, 1) = File.datelastModified
                        With .Offset(0, 2)
                            .Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(File.Size / 1024, 1)
                            .NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
                        End With
                    End With
                    'Add Total From this file to current workbook
                    With .Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
                        .Offset(0, 4) = 

                    End With
                End With
            End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm having a few problems however :(
Number one is that it won't exclude all the file extensions i've put in there... for instance .bat won't be selected, but .txt and .xlsm will. Don't know how to fix that.

Number two is, that i just don't know how to copy the information from the excel files that are being listed. I think it has to be done at the following part almost at the bottom "'Adds each file, details and hyperlinks to the list"
At the last "with" i'm trying to get the data from the file so far i've come up with nothing :( The data i'm trying to fetch are some numbers in a couple of fields on the first sheet of each workbook.

I think the code has to come after ".Offset(0, 4)" but please help me!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you :

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Function Excludes(Ext As String) As Boolean
     'Function purpose:  To exclude listed file extensions from hyperlink listing

    Dim X, NumPos As Long

     'Enter/adjust file extensions to EXCLUDE from listing here:
    X = Array("exe", "bat", "dll", "zip", "txt", "xlsm", "html", "htm", "xml")

    On Error Resume Next
    NumPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Ext, X, 0)
    If NumPos > 0 Then
        Excludes = True
    Else
        Excludes = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

For extensions filters, check your old function, but I'm pretty sure there wasn't any "False" return as you didn't set it in your code.

Then you have to open the workbook to actually get data from it :

```
Sub HyperlinkFileList()
     'Macro purpose:  To create a hyperlinked list of all files in a user
     'specified directory, including file size and date last modified
     'NOTE:  The 'TextToDisplay' property (of the Hyperlink object) was added
     'in Excel 2000.  This code tests the Excel version and does not use the
     'Texttodisplay property if using XL 97.

    Dim fso As Object, _
    ShellApp As Object, _
    File As Object, _
    SubFolder As Object, _
    Directory As String, _
    Problem As Boolean, _
    ExcelVer As Integer, _
    TotalD As String, _
    Wb As Workbook, _
    Ws As Worksheet


     'Turn off screen flashing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     ' Clear sheet
    Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'Useless : Range("A1").Select

     'Create objects to get a listing of all files in the directory
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

     'Prompt user to select a directory
    Do
        Problem = False
        Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
        Browseforfolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, "D:")
        'Browseforfolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, "D:\JBOSS\Testdossier")

        On Error Resume Next
         'Evaluate if directory is valid
        Directory = ShellApp.self.Path
        Set SubFolder = fso.GetFolder(Directory).Files
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            If MsgBox("You did not choose a valid directory!" & vbCrLf & _
            "Would you like to try again?", vbYesNoCancel, _
            "Directory Required") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
            Problem = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop Until Problem = False

     'Set up the headers on the worksheet
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("A1")
            .Value = "Listing of all files in:"
            .ColumnWidth = 40
             'If Excel 2000 or greater, add hyperlink with file name
             'displayed.  If earlier, add hyperlink with full path displayed
            If Val(Application.Version) > 8 Then 'Using XL2000+
                .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=.Offset(0, 1), _
                Address:=Directory, _
                TextToDisplay:=Directory
            Else 'Using XL97
                .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=.Offset(0, 1), _
                Address:=Directory
            End If
        End With

        With .Range("A2")
            .Value = "File Name"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            .ColumnWidth = 50
            With .Offset(0, 1)
                .ColumnWidth = 15
                .Value = "Date Modified"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 2)
                .ColumnWidth = 12
                .Value = "File Size (Kb)"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 3)
                .ColumnWidth = 18
                .Value = "Status testdossier"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 4)
                .ColumnWidth = 22
                .Value = "Totaal aantal testgevallen"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 5)
                .ColumnWidth = 15
                .Value = "Uitgevoerd"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 6)
                .ColumnWidth = 15
                .Value = "Akkoord"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 7)
                .ColumnWidth = 6
                .Value = "OK"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 8)
                .ColumnWidth = 6
                .Value = "NOK"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        End With
    End With

     'Adds each file, details and hyperlinks to the list
    For Each File In SubFolder
            If Not Excludes(Right(File.Path, 3)) = True Then
                With ActiveSheet
                     'If Excel 2000 or greater, add hyperlink with file name
                     'displayed.  If earlier, add hyperlink with full path displayed
                    If Val(Application.Version) > 8 Then 'Using XL2000+
                        .Hyperlinks.Add _
                        Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
                        Address:=File.Path, _
                        TextToDisplay:=File.Name
                    Else 'Using XL97
                        .Hyperlinks.Add _
                        Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
                        Address:=File.Path
                    End If
                    'Add date last modified, and size in KB
                    With .Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
                        .Offset(0, 1) = File.datelastModified
                        With .Offset(0, 2)
                            .Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(File.Size / 1024, 1)
                            .NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
                        End With
                    End With
                    'Add Total From this file to current workbook
                    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(File)
                    Set Ws = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

                    With .Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
                        .Offset(0, 4) = Ws.Range("A1")
                    End With

                    Wb.Close
                    Set Wb = Nothing
                    Set Ws = Nothing
                End With
            End If
    Next File

     'Turn back on screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much R3uK!
TotalD As String, _ hasn't been used later on in the code, so I had to remove that, but that was no problem at all.

I'm just not sure why the blacklisting of files doesn't seem to work very well. Also a collegue suggested using white listing, which made sense :)

Figuring that out now :)